# Как правильно написать в официальном документе фразу

Tags: лексика

"Подано письменное заявление Иванова Ивана Ивановича о предоставлении ему (ей) работодателем сведений о трудовой деятельности в соответствии со статьей 66.1 Трудового кодекса Российской Федерации (часть 2 статьи 2 Федерального закона от 16 декабря 2019 г. № 439-ФЗ)".

"Подано письменное заявление Ивановым Иваном Ивановичем о предоставлении ему (ей) работодателем сведений о трудовой деятельности в соответствии со статьей 66.1 Трудового кодекса Российской Федерации (часть 2 статьи 2 Федерального закона от 16 декабря 2019 г. № 439-ФЗ)".

Answer (score 1):

По грамматике второй вариант явно предпочтителен.
***Подано письменное заявление Ивановым Иваном Ивановичем о предоставлении...***

Но меня смущают слова "правильно" и "официальный документ". Если это документ утвержденной формы, то там иногда встречаются такие обороты, что не до правильности -- смысл бы понять. Спорить с такими вещами обычно бесполезно.
Поэтому моё предложение можете воспринять как рекомендацию, но не более, "правильно" же будет так, как это написано в образце или инструкции по сочинению таких документов.

ПС. Если это заявление в суд или ответ на затребованные судом сведения, то то опыту знаю, что там на эти тонкости внимания обычно не обращают. Впрочем, в этом случае не проблема и у юриста спросить.